# How to convert escaped JSON-string to NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am working with a http-server, which return JSON-string in response body:

```
"Some text.\nSome text.\n\t\"Some text in quotes.\""
```

I need remove quotes in the start and end of string, and I need unescape special symbols. I make category for NSString, but I think that it is wrong implementation: https://gist.github.com/virasio/59907e087f859e6c1723
I have other idea. I can use NSJSONSerialization:

```
NSString *sourceString = @"\"Some text.\\nSome text.\\n\\t\\\"Some text in quotes.\\\"\"";
NSString *jsonObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ \"value\" : %@ }", sourceString];
NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonObject dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding options:0 error:NULL]];
NSString *result = [object objectForKey:@"value"];
```

But... It is not good too.

Comment: Pass it a pointer to an NSError and NSLog the error after the failed serialisation.  That will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @JeremyP, thanks for idea, but I haven't problem really, I have problem in my brain. :) I think, that can be exists more beautiful method.

Comment: how are you getting the response?

Comment: @ColdLogic, used NSConnection and converted NSData to NSString.

Comment: @ColdLogic, yes, server developer is making this coded response, but I tired debating about it with him (that I not need response encoding on server).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Foundation will only parse JSON objects or arrays, but it can parse strings, numbers and booleans if you tell it to accept JSON fragments:

```c
NSData *data = [@"\"Some text.\\nSome text.\\n\\t\\\"Some text in quotes.\\\"\""
    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                            options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                              error:NULL];
NSLog(@"[result class] = %@", [result class]);
NSLog(@"result = %@", result);
```

Yields:

> ```
> [result class] = __NSCFString
> result = Some text.
> Some text.
>   "Some text in quotes."
> ```

This is actually one of the cases where passing `error` really helps.  I had tried without passing `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` and got a very clear error message:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (**JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.**)

Comment: Thanks! Why I can't found option NSJSONReadingAllowFragments earlier? :)

Comment: "So, a string by itself is perfectly valid JSON". Not really, see here for reference: [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). The problem the OP is facing stems from elsewhere, probably an incorrect encoding on the server side.